# Shell: how to evaluate an arithmetic expression with more than two operands

Tags: bash, shell, expression

I have read several posts but they are talking about two operands

I have got the following expression that is to be evaluated:

> sum = a / b * 100

In the bash shell, I can do:

```
bash-4.1$ a=5
bash-4.1$ b=10
bash-4.1$ sum=`expr $a / $b`
bash-4.1$ echo $sum
0
```

However, I cannot do:

```
bash-4.1$ sum=`expr $a / $b * 100`
expr: syntax error
```

Comment: you need to escape expr's `*` , otherwise, before expr is even invoked, it will be expanded by the shell into a list of filenames

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
result=$(echo "($a/$b) * $c)" | bc -l)
```

Try bc.

For integers: `echo $(( 10 /5 *200 ))`

Comment: you can even put the assignment into the arithmetic expression: `((sum=a*100/b))` -- do the multiplication first to preserve as much precision as possible with integer arithmetic. The shell will expand variables without dollar signs in an arithmetic expression

Comment: Note that `(( ... ))` is an extension used by some, but not all shells. `: $((sum=a*100/b))` is the equivalent in POSIX shells.

Comment: Indeed, the example you are are referring to is POSIX arithmetic expansion. Sec 2.3 http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html